# Conent of <a> doesn't center in a <ul> list item (horizontal menu)

Tags: html, css

I just started developing my first web page after learning HTML and CSS and I don't have much understanding yet.

The issue is, as mentioned, problem with centering. I have specified CSS property `text-align: cetner;` but that has no result.

Another thing I couldn't achieve is to expand link clickable area to whole button. I mean, wherever you click on a button, the browser should go to the URL from the link, I tried specifying `width: 100%;` with no success.

Below is my code:

```css
li.hMenu {
    display: inline;
    background: red;
    width: 33.33%; /*for the older browsers fallback */
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
}

li.hMenu:hover{
    background-color: darkred;
}

li.hMenu:active{
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background-color: darkred;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CommonLayout.css" />
    <script src="ProjectPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li style="z-index: 10" class="hMenu">
            <a href="ProjectPage.html">Main Page</a>
        </li>
        <li style="z-index: 9" class="hMenu">
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li style="z-index: 8" class="hMenu">
            <a href="Calculator.html">Calculator</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p>This is <em>Main Page</em> page.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: make your `a` block instead of inline-block and your are done

Comment: also remove inline from li, useless

Comment: @TemaniAfif So obvious, yet I didn't think of it. Thanks ! Why is `inline` useless? I am shocked that it actually works, I thought, that without it it will become normal list. Can give me some reference or short explanation? Also, you can put all this info in answer, I'll gladly accept and upvote!

Comment: because you have float:left which make the inline useless ... you simply need to check how float works and you will understand ;)

Comment: Oh, so, can I think of `<ul>` as a container for `<li>` elements? That would explain a lot :)

Comment: you don't have to think, it's the container for your li element ;)

Comment: you need to also clear float, so add `overflow: auto;` to the ul and remove float from ul, it's useless too ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change your anchor element's display property to block:

```
li a {
    display: block;
```

This way it will take up 100% of it's containing boxes width and your text-align property will take affect.

```css
li.hMenu {
    display: inline;
    background: red;
    width: 33.33%; /*for the older browsers fallback */
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    float: left;
}

li.hMenu:hover{
    background-color: darkred;
}

li.hMenu:active{
    position: relative;
    left: 1px;
    top: 1px;
    background-color: darkred;
}

#menu {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}

li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CommonLayout.css" />
    <script src="ProjectPage.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="menu">
        <li style="z-index: 10" class="hMenu">
            <a href="ProjectPage.html">Main Page</a>
        </li>
        <li style="z-index: 9" class="hMenu">
            <a href="About.html">About</a>
        </li>
        <li style="z-index: 8" class="hMenu">
            <a href="Calculator.html">Calculator</a>
        </li>
    </ul>

    <p>This is <em>Main Page</em> page.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change this code block:

```
li.hMenu {
text-align: center;
display: inline;
background: red;
width: 33.33%;
width: calc(100% / 3);
float: left; }
```

Comment: you have use text-align css styling on only containers of the element.